# How to organize URLs in django for views handling GET data and parsing URL?

Tags: django, url

I have a view that displays some movie data. I thought that it might be a good idea to have a view handle a an URL like `movie-id/1234` to search for movie id 1234. Furthermore I would like to be able to enter the ID into a form and send that to a server and search for it. To do that I created a second entry in the `urls.py` file shown below.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'movie-id/(?P<movie_id>.+?)/$', 'movieMan.views.detailMovie'),
    url(r'movie-id/$', 'movieMan.views.detailMovie', name='movieMan.detailMovie.post'),
)
```

So if I want to pass data to my view either via a URL or a GET or POST request I have to enter two urls or is there a more elegant way? In the view's code I am then checking if there is any GET data in the incoming request.

To make the second url usable with the template engine, where I wanted to specify the view's url using the `{% url movieMan.detailMovie.post %}` syntax I had to introduce a name attribute on this url to distinguish between these two.

I am not sure if I am thinking too complicated here. I am now asking myself what is the first url entry good for? Is there a way to get the URL of a movie directly? When do these kinds of URLs come into play and how would they be generated in the template ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Furthermore I would like to be able to enter the ID into a form and
>   send that to a server and search for it.

Is this actually a search? Because if you know the ID, and the ID is a part of the URL, you could just have a textbox where the user can write in the ID, and you do a redirect with javascript to the 'correct' URL. If the ID doesn't exist, the view should return a [Http404](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#the-http404-exception).

If you mean an actual search, i.e. the user submitting a query string, you'll need some kind of list/result view, in which case you'll be generating all the links to the specific results, which you will be sure are correct.

Comment: Then I would always need some Javascript to submit data in addition to my usual <form> element. Well, with jQuery it would be a piece of cake. However I do not really know what the nice url with the ID in the end is good for.

Comment: The url with the ID uniquely identifies a resource; in your case a movie. If you do a real search somewhere, you can refer to each unique result. re:javascript: Yes, that's because the user is submitting an **id**. You don't actually need a form at all, and certainly not one that sends data to the server, just javascript which makes a link from the content of an input field.

Comment: Let's assume one would have a list of movies which are links to the movie's details. How would you generate the urls? Like this: `{% url movieMan.views.detailMovie movie.id %}` where `movie` represents one movie object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a more elegant way.

I did almost the same thing:

```
url( r'^movies/search/((?P<query_string>[^/]+)/)?$', 'mediadb.views.search_movies' ),
```

The url pattern matches urls with or without a search parameter.
In the view-function, you will have to check whether the parameter was defined in the url or in the query string.